# Error include functions.php

Tags: php, function

I have 2 pages :

- functions.php

  ```
  function get_test($name) {
      return 'Yo '.$name.' !';
  }
  ```
- test.php

  ```
  include('http://www.exemple.com/functions.php');
  echo get_test(Thomas);
  ```

When I execute my script on the server :

**Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_test() in /htdocs/test.php on line 5**

*Note: I don't use Wordpress*
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do this:

```
include('http://www.exemple.com/functions.php');
```

It causes PHP to issue a full-blown HTTP request to your own server, causing Apache to **EXECUTE** that script, and return its output. That means you're not getting PHP code. You're getting the OUTPUT of that php code, which is not likely to be valid PHP code.

include/require via HTTP is almost always a sign of bad design, and also a major security vulnerability, if you're include/requiring from an actual remote url. Nothing says that the remote url can't return something like `<?php system('rm -rf /'); ?>`, which your server will then happily start executing.

Almost certainly you only need something like this:

```
include('functions.php');
```

Comment: Ok nice but if `functions.php` are in subfolder ?

Comment: so figure out an appropriate LOCAL path for that. there any number of questions on this site on how to use paths for includes

Comment: Also read about php auto loading, so you don't have to include(); every script